# Dimension of vector space when you remove a vector

Tags: vector-spaces

if $U$ a vector space with $dim(U)<f$, and when we remove one vector does the dimension increase or not ($dim(U)\geq f$?

I want to understand the following proof of theorem

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You remove one vector from what?

Comment: You're removing *just* one vector? What you get isn't a vector space (so doesn't have a vector space dimension).

Comment: The picture doesn't say "vector space" at all.  And "number of edges out of $S$" does not sound like linear algebra, either.

Comment: I don't understand the image you've now included at all. Way too much missing context.

Comment: And I agree with GEdgar that it doesn't really look like linear algebra. More background about what you're working on would help.

Comment: this in reality vector space and graph theory

Answer (score 1):

The dimension decreases , in the f.d case, if you remove a *basis* vector. The vector space spanned by the basis {$v_1,..,v_{n-1}$} is lower than the dimension of the vector space spanned by {$v_1,...,v_n$}

Comment: I will add picture and lock just the yellow part

Comment: if $A$ contains all sets $U$ s.t $dim(U)<f$.in the last part ,of pecture we have $U \setminus \{Z\}\not \in A$ this mean $dim(U  \setminus\{Z\})>=f$

Comment: @MokhTarBou: This seems like a nonstandard use of the term vector space.

Comment: @MokhTarBou: Do you have the title of the section you pasted in? Maybe the name of the chapter?

Comment: I have add the theorem and the proof

Comment: One more thing, sorry, could you please quote the definition of dimension you are using, from your book/notes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62694/discussion-between-mokh-tar-bou-and-gary).

Comment: I would like to thank all who try for helping me , and this my problem i need to put a lot of definition before so excuse me.